# How to enter two strings together with gets();

Tags: string, cin, gets

I was wondering if there is a way to enter a string together like how we enter `cin>>a>>b;`
How can we do the same using `gets` for strings?

Comment: If `cin>>a>>b;` works, why are you looking for another way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

This is three months late, but it's probably worth writing since the only other answer is wildly off.

First, and most importantly, **don't use gets()**. There is no way to use it safely: it might as well be called `overrun_my_buffer_and_crash_my_program_if_I_am_lucky()`. There's a reason it's been removed from the latest C standard.

Second, `cin >> a >> b;` reads two whitespace-delimited strings, such as two words in a sentence. `gets()` and its much safer cousin `fgets()` read in a whole line, delimited by the newline character `'\n'` (note that they do **not** stop at other whitespace characters!). It is therefore much harder to replicate the behavior of `cin` - you'll have to do all the parsing yourself. (This is not saying it can't be done; if you have to do it in C, checkout `strtok()`).

The C equivalent of `cin >> a >> b;` is `scanf()`: `char a[80], b[80]; scanf("%79s %79s", a, b);` However, note that you can only read in strings up to a fixed maximum length (in this example 79 characters). It's fairly complicated to safely read in a string of arbitrary length in C; you'll need to read them in fixed-size chunks, and allocate sufficient memory to combine the chunks together.

Answer (score -2):

If your input strings are separated with some sort of whitespace (i.e. " ", "\n" etc.), then it will simply be:

```
gets(s1);
gets(s2);
```

Another way is to use an [`fgets(char* str, int num, FILE* stream)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). It can be used twice for str1 and str2, and will take an input from stream into string until either num-1 chars was read, or eos ("\n", "\t", etc.) is reached. This function is strongly recommended, as it is more safe, than gets.

There also is a third, much more complicated way of doing this: you can define your own string class (inherited from std::string), and define an operator there, which will be standing for gets() or fgets(); but this option is really too complicated and unuseful for your situation.

If it is necessary for you to use one function, then you can create an overloaded gets() for two strings:

```
    void  gets(char * str1, char * str2)
{
      gets(str1);
      gets(str2);
}
```

The same trick can be done with fgets. But again, isn't it too complicated for you just to make 2 calls of gets() or fgets()?

Comment: This is wrong. `gets` reads a line terminated by a newline; other whitespace is just part of the line. Furthermore, `gets` is inherently unsafe, and should *never* be used (it's even been removed from C as of the 2011 standard).